# Can we profile per core with dtrace?

Tags: c, linux, dtrace

Is `dtrace` usable in multithreaded applications, and can I profile individual cores? If so, would someone point me to an example?

Answer (score 1):

DTrace is very suitable for lock analysis, due to it's ability to dynamically instrument lock events as required. The following commands and providers can be used for lock analysis, and were first shipped with the Solaris 10.

AS dtrace is usable for identify the lock analysis it can be used in multithreaded application  you can check on http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/DTrace_Topics_Locks

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different scripts [here](http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html), for example threaded.d - sample multi-threaded CPU usage.